# ACPI (Advanced Configuration And Power Configuration) not present on 2.6.38.8?

Tags: kernel, power-management

I need to disable some parts in **ACPI**, but it is
simply not present in kernel **2.6.38.8** *(downloaded
as a tar from net)*?

I can see the option in kernel **2.6.34-12** (default
on OpenSuse 11.3), but not in the other one.

What's the point that I am missing?

P.S.
Screen shots are from kernel 2.6.38.8.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ACPI block depends on PCI being enabled.

```
Symbol: ACPI [=y]
...
  Depends on: !IA64_HP_SIM && (IA64 || X86 [=y]) && PCI [=y]
```

If you disabled PCI (or didn't enable it), or selected a different architecture, you won't see any options related to ACPI.

Comment: BTW, where did you find this written? `Depends on: !IA64_HP_SIM && (IA64 || X86 [=y]) && PCI [=y]` I can't see it in my screenshots.

Comment: It's the help text for the selector... that is hidden if you don't have PCI enabled.

Comment: Mat, thanks but that's not helpful on the part of kernel. :(

Comment: I think it might be accessible in 3.x kernels, but can't test right now. Kconfig is a bit quirky.